# Count with conditions in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, count, conditional-statements

I have the following DF:

```
    Week   SKU   Discount(%)
     1     111       5
     2     111       5
     3     111       0
     4     111      10
     1     222       0
     2     222      10
     3     222      15
     4     222      20
     1     333       5
     2     333       0
     3     333       0
```

I would like to have this outcome:

```
    Week   SKU   Discount(%)   Duration  LastDiscount
     1     111       5            2           0
     2     111       5            2           0
     3     111       0            0           0
     4     111      10            1           2
     1     222       0            0           0
     2     222      10            3           0
     3     222      15            3           0
     4     222      20            3           0
     1     333       5            1           0
     2     333       0            0           0
     3     333       0            0           0
```

Duration is the number of weeks that 1 SKU had discounts continuously.
LastDiscount counts the number of weeks from the last time the SKU was on a continuous discount, only if there are weeks with 0 in between discounts.

Comment: `LastDiscount` counts the weeks since the last discount in the same SKU, even if the discounts are different from one week to the next one, I'm only counting the weeks without discounts. The 4th row has 10% discount in SKU 111, the last time It has a discount was in the 2nd row, so there were 2 weeks without a discount in that SKU. On the other hand, the SKU 222 had 3 different discounts from the 2nd to 4th week so there were no weeks without discounts, that explain the 0. For SKU 333 after the 5% discount there is no other discount, so that is why the count is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option to check the "Duration' is after grouping by 'SKU', use `rle` (run-length-encoding) on a logical vector, gets the `lengths` and 'values' and `rep`licate those duration.  Similarly, the "LastDiscount" can be obtained by getting the `sum` of logical values

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(SKU) %>% 
  mutate(Duration = with(rle(Discount > 0), rep(lengths*values, 
        lengths)),
         temp = with(rle(Discount > 0), sum(values != 0)), 
         LastDiscount = if(temp[1] > 1) c(rep(0, n()-1), temp[1]) else 0) %>%
  select(-temp)
# A tibble: 11 x 5
# Groups:   SKU [3]
#    Week   SKU Discount Duration LastDiscount
#   <int> <int>    <int>    <int>        <dbl>
# 1     1   111        5        2            0
# 2     2   111        5        2            0
# 3     3   111        0        0            0
# 4     4   111       10        1            2
# 5     1   222        0        0            0
# 6     2   222       10        3            0
# 7     3   222       15        3            0
# 8     4   222       20        3            0
# 9     1   333        5        1            0
#10     2   333        0        0            0
#11     3   333        0        0            0
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df1)[, grp := rleid(Discount > 0), SKU][Discount > 0,
  Duration := .N,  .(grp, SKU)][, 
   LastDiscount := uniqueN(grp[Discount > 0]), .(SKU)][, 
   tail(.I[Discount > 0 & LastDiscount > 1], 1), SKU]$V1
df1[-i1, LastDiscount := 0][]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Week = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L), SKU = c(111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 
333L, 333L, 333L), Discount = c(5L, 5L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 10L, 15L, 
20L, 5L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L
))
```

Comment: How can i repeat the values for `LastDiscount` if for the SKU 111 in the 5th week there was a discount. I would like to repeat the 2 for that next week as well. Thanks!

Comment: @dmatiasbayona  Can you please post as a new question

Comment: I posted a new question, I'm trying something a little bit different please help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59242628/counting-repeating-with-conditions-r

Comment: @dmatiasbayona  There is a solution posted there.  Can you check if that is right

Comment: Yes, I tried that but the problem is that if I have a different DF where I had a row between week 4, 5 for the SKU 111, the value 2, would move to that new row instead of the 4th row which started the new chain of weeks with discount.