# Counting/repeating with conditions R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

From a question I asked before ([Count with conditions in R dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59204544/count-with-conditions-in-r-dataframe/59204582#59204582)), I have the following table:

```
  Week   SKU   Discount(%)   Duration  LastDiscount
     1     111       5            2           0
     2     111       5            2           0
     3     111       0            0           0
     4     111      10            2           0
     5     111      11            2           2
     1     222       0            0           0
     2     222      10            3           0
     3     222      15            3           0
     4     222      20            3           0
```

I want the `LastDiscount` count to be in the first row where there is a different discount for the same SKU in different weeks. For example, the SKU 111 had a discount in the 2nd week and the next discount is in the 4th week, that gives 2 weeks since the last discount but the problem is that I want the result to be in the 4th week where starts the next discount campaign.

Something like this:

```
  Week   SKU   Discount(%)   Duration  LastDiscount
     1     111       5            2           0
     2     111       5            2           0
     3     111       0            0           0
     4     111      10            2           2
     5     111      11            2           0
     1     222       0            0           0
     2     222      10            3           0
     3     222      15            3           0
     4     222      20            3           0
```

I have this code right now:

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(SKU) %>% 
  mutate(Duration = with(rle(Discount > 0), rep(lengths*values, 
        lengths)),
         temp = with(rle(Discount > 0), sum(values != 0)), 
         LastDiscount = if(temp[1] > 1) c(rep(0, n()-1), temp[1]) else 0) %>%
  select(-temp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `data.table`. I will delete it if OP is only looking for a `dplyr` solution:

```
#calculate duration of discount and also the start and end of discount period
DT[, c("Duration", "disc_seq") := {
        dur <- sum(`Discount(%)` > 0L)
        disc_seq <- rep("", .N)
        if (dur > 0) {
            disc_seq[1L] <- "S"
            disc_seq[length(disc_seq)] <- "E"
        }
        .(dur, disc_seq)
    }, 
    .(SKU, rleid(`Discount(%)` > 0L))]
DT[]

#use a non-equi join to find the end of previous discount period to update LastDiscount column of the start of current discount period
DT[, LastDiscount := 0L]
DT[disc_seq=="S", LastDiscount := {
        ld <- DT[disc_seq=="E"][.SD, on=.(SKU, Week<Week), by=.EACHI, i.Week - x.Week]$V1
        replace(ld, is.na(ld), 0L)
    }]
DT[]
```

output:

```
   Week SKU Discount(%) Duration disc_seq LastDiscount
1:    1 111           5        2        S            0
2:    2 111           5        2        E            0
3:    3 111           0        0                     0
4:    4 111          10        2        S            2
5:    5 111          11        2        E            0
6:    1 222           0        0                     0
7:    2 222          10        3        S            0
8:    3 222          15        3                     0
9:    4 222          20        3        E            0
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("Week   SKU   Discount(%)
1     111       5
2     111       5
3     111       0
4     111      10
5     111      11
1     222       0
2     222      10
3     222      15
4     222      20")
```

Comment: I got the following message for the discount duration:
 `Error in .(SKU, rleid(Discount(%)L)) : could not find function "."`
And for the `LastDiscount` this:
`Error in `:=`(ENTREDESC, 0L) : Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").`

Comment: When I change the DF I got the following error: `Error in `[.data.table`(DT, disc_seq == "S", `:=`(LastDiscount, { : Supplied 10 items to be assigned to 9 items of column 'LastDiscount'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.`

Answer (score 0):

Is the LastDiscount always one row below where it should be?  If so, you can do this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(LastDiscount2=lead(LastDiscount))
```